# How to parametrize results from a query to use in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server Management Studio, say that I have a query that produces these results:

```
SELECT TOP 5 names 
FROM name.Names
```

```
|   Names  |
|----------|
|   John   |
| Cathleen |
|  Joseph  |
|  Robert  |
|   Bob    |
```

I then have a stored procedure that looks for these names and performs other functions etc. The issue is right now  I insert these names manually into a parameter so:

```
@Names = 'John, Cathleen, Joseph, Robert, Bob'
```

Is there a way to "tie" the query to the variable so whatever the query outputs the parameter takes as input.

Comment: Not at all a bad question, actually. I don't think typical SQL can "pipeline" queries, but let's wait for other answers. +1

Comment: it might better with CLR or fetch approach in SP to apply some action on each name

Comment: It's not clear from your question but are you trying to construct a csv from your first query or are you trying to pass the result of your first query to a subseqent procedure for processing?

Comment: Suggest you read Erland's discussion of [arrays and lists](https://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html) and bookmark the main page as it contains much useful information.

Answer (score 1):

May be following approach could be a way to resolve your issue where you need to define your own table type, fill it, and pass it to procedure.

However this requires changing a little bit your stored procedure (in params list your custom type should be followed by READONLY):

```
    CREATE TYPE User_Names AS TABLE(
        Name VARCHAR(50)       
    )
```

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE myStoredProcedure(@user_Names [User_Names] READONLY)  
    AS  
    BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO dbo.User
    (  
      Name
    )  
    SELECT * FROM @user_Names;  
    END
```

```
    DECLARE @userNames AS User_Names;
    
    INSERT INTO @userNames
    SELECT Name  
    EXEC myStoredProcedure @userNames;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 WITH CTE(NAME)AS
  (
    SELECT 'JOHN'
      UNION ALL
    SELECT 'JACK'
      UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ROBERT'
 )
 SELECT STRING_AGG(C.NAME,',')
 FROM CTE AS C
```

For SQL Server 2017 and later you can use STRING_AGG

Comment: So I have SQL Server Management Studio 17 but when I run this code I get this error: 'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @Paradox: whether or not the feature is available depends on the SQL Server **engine** - the core - not the Management Studio version. Run `SELECT @@VERSION` on your database to get the version of the SQL Server engine you're running against

Comment: it depends which SQL server version you are running. for older versions on Google you can find a split functions and concatinate/aggregate functions.
STRING_AGG was made publicly available as of SQL Server 2017

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @Names varchar(max)
set @Names = 'John, Cathleen, Joseph, Robert, Bob'

SELECT * from STRING_SPLIT(@Names, ',')
```

[image]

and reversed

```
Declare @NamesTable TABLE (Names varchar(10))
insert @NamesTable values
('John'), ('Cathleen'), ('Joseph'), ('Robert'), ('Bob')

select * from @NamesTable

SELECT STRING_AGG (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max),Names), ',') AS result
FROM @NamesTable
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The typical solution -- that I don't like too much -- is to assemble the result set into a single value, that can be fed to the procedure.

This assembled list of values can take the form of:

- a JSON doc,
- an XML doc,
- a CSV text, or even
- an array.

Of course, your procedure would need be tweaked to parse the assembled value accordingly. This definitively works (between some size boundaries), but still don't like it too much. Of course you can't fit 10 million values in a solution like this one.

I hope there was a better solution, though.